# Why are the wrong array values being printed?

Tags: c

For some reason, the nested `for` loop I have created at the bottom seems to be printing out the wrong first value (Gives me 3, when it should be 8). Yet, when I simply do `printf` (at the bottom), I am given the right value. Not really sure what's wrong with my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int d;
    printf("Please input dimensions: (between 3 and 9, inclusive): \n");
    scanf("%i", &d);

    int array[d][d];

    int k = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = (d * d) - k; //d^2 doesn't work to square a function
            k++;
        }
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < d; z++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < d; y++)   
        {
            printf("%i\n", array[z][y]);
        }      
    }

    printf("%i\n", array[0][0]);
    printf("%i\n", array[0][1]);
}
```

Edit: Sorry guys, the top value that was being printed was my own input. I was simply thinking it was the first value being printed.

Comment: You would have gotten several print outputs depending on the value of `d`.  Are you certain that you are comparing the correct values of `array`?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems yet. What if you change the `printf` in your loop to `printf("array[%i][%i] = %i\n", z, y, array[z][y]);` to be sure that you're looking at the correct values?

Comment: Are you sure the first value printed isn't actually the value of `d` you are inputting?

Comment: It appears to work as you intend on  ideone: http://ideone.com/Cf4F8Z -- I had to get rid of the non standard header

Comment: Please show your input `d` and your output

Comment: I think @dbush is right. If you're expecting 8, obviously you have `d == 3`

Comment: Just a note: if I chose `d` to be `1`, `printf("%i\n", array[0][1]);` is out of bound access.

Comment: Hey guys. So I run the program, input "3" when asked to "input dimensions" and get the following output: 3
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
8
7

@SouravGhosh The dimensions have to be between 3 and 9, inclusive.

Comment: Other than the rather awkward `z`, `y` ordering of the second set of loops (nothing wrong with `i, j` again), your code is doing what you are telling it to without any undefined behavior. You should *validate* all user input (e.g. `if (scanf ("%d", &d) != 1 || (d < 3 || 9 < d)) return 1;`), but it is working as you describe you intend.

Comment: Shit. I'm sorry. I've been staring at the screen for hours, and completely blanked. What I was looking at is my own input....

Comment: @ManuelStoilov and if I were you, I never believed the user to abide by the screen prompt. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh You're completely right man. I have yet to go over my program and fix all of those things. Thanks for catching that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you aren't looking at your own input? I cut and paste and see:

```
Please input dimensions: (between 3 and 9, inclusive): 
3
8
7
6
5
...
```

The 3 is actually what I typed and is echoed.